# Qualtrics Javascript Runs Inconsistently on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, qualtrics

As part of our research, we collect surveys from participants using Qualtrics. Qualtrics has a neat little feature where you can embed bits of Javascript into a question. We have a study where we need to calculate the difference in days from when they completed their first survey compared to when they are completing their current survey, but the calculation seems to work inconsistently on mobile devices. The code right now looks like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
  var surv1date=new Date("${e://Field/day1date}");
      surv1date.setHours(0);
      surv1date.setMinutes(0);
      surv1date.setSeconds(0);
      surv1date.setMilliseconds(0);

  var one_day=86400000;

  var difference = Math.abs(todayDate.getTime() - surv1date.getTime())/one_day + 1;
  Math.round(difference);

var intCount = 1;
var daydiff = null;

    do {    
  //$('daydiff').value = Math.round(difference);
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('daydiff', Math.round(difference));
    daydiff = Math.round(difference);
    intCount++;
}
while (intCount <= 10  && (daydiff == undefined || daydiff == null || daydiff == NaN || isNaN(daydiff) == true));

    var strday = "on Day ";
    var strfinal = strday.concat(daydiff);
    var newQuestionText = questionText.replace("on Day", strfinal);

    $(this.questionContainer).down('.QuestionText').innerHTML = newQuestionText;

});
;
```

On mobile devices, it appears sometimes that this code is not running correctly and daydiff is not calculated, but other times it works fine. It will work one day and not the next on the same phone, same browser, same everything. I set it up to loop through the daydiff calculation up to 10 times thinking that might make a difference. We've seen the problem on both iOS and Android devices, but never on a desktop device. Javascript was enabled on these devices. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it isn't working on mobile devices, but two ideas:

1) I don't see where you are defining todayDate as a date object.  Don't you need:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
```

before the difference calculation?

2) You could take the device and browser out of the equation by calling a simple web service from the survey flow to do the calculation.  It could be a simple php script that you pass day1date to and it returns the difference. A side benefit is that you would be using a consistent time source.